# How to update Github Maven repository in Intellij?

Tags: maven, github, intellij-idea, maven-3

I am using `IntelliJ 14.1.4` and updating a remote `maven` repository does not work as expected.

I get this error message:

```
Exception: Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist
```

[image]

How can I fix this issue?